# Are the kernels which are used in ubuntu and fedora or any Linux based OS same?

Tags: linux-kernel

The kernels which are used in various Linux based OS are same or they are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all based on the version found on kernel.org, but they usually add their own patches and backport fixes and hardware support.

For the most part the differences are not something to worry about.